# Check versioning outside the market without download .apk file

Tags: android

Is it possible to check the version of a remote .apk file without download it? I suppose not but i try ask :)
My idea was to poll for a new version every time the app starts, but if i've to download the .apk every time it becomes too eavy.

Comment: Would you be hosting the apk yourself?

Comment: Yes, i will be hosting the apk on my web domain.

Answer (score 0):

An APK is a zip file. You can examine the AndroidManifest.xml file in the zip archive and take a look at the app's version number.

Comment: AFAIK AndroidManifest.xml in a .apk file is compiled (it is a binary file). So I doubt you can do that.

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml file is partially encrypted in a signed APK file. You can see the app name and version number. The data such as permissions and intent class names are obscured.

Comment: So is it possible to read only the AndroidManifest.xml without download the entire .apk file from the web server? If yes how can i do that, can you give a simple example. I nedd only to see the version-code. Thank you ;)

Comment: I would think that you do need to download the entire APK file to see the AndroidManifest.xml file because you can't know for sure what order the files are placed in the archive. If the Android dev tools store the manifest first, then you may be able to do a partial download.

Comment: Yes i think the same. I solved putting the versione in the name of the remote APK file. Then i test in background with am AsynkTask and HttpURLConnection if a file exist with version number greater then versionCode and only in that case i download the APK and do the job. I know, it's not clean but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're hosting/uploading the apk yourself, you can check to see if the file's timestamp on the server has changed (i.e. you have uploaded a new apk), and if it has, download the new apk.

Comment: Yes, but to do that i've to compare the timestamp server-side with the one client-side (which i've to store somewhere the first time i donwload the .apk). On the contrary, doing like i did, i find the version code directly in file name and i can quickly compare it with the actual version code of the app. Yes, i've to be careful when i'll put the new version on server side to write down the right name to the .apk